# Improving Performance of Content-Based Image Retrieval using Color Histograms in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am working on Content-Based Image Retrieval and Precision-Recall graphs using Color Histograms in MATLAB. Since, I have 1000 images in my database. When i query input image it takes around 12 seconds to execute and show PR curve. I am curious to know that, How do I improve the performance?

Code:

```
% Dir: parent directory location for images folder c1, c2, c3
% inputImage: \c1\1.ppm
% For example to get P-R curve execute: CBIR('D:\visionImages','\c2\1.ppm');
function [  ] = demoCBIR( Dir,inputImage)
% Dir='D:\visionImages';
% inputImage='\c3\1.ppm';
tic;
S=strcat(Dir,inputImage);
Inp1=imread(S);
num_red_bins = 8;
num_green_bins = 8;
num_blue_bins = 8;
num_bins = num_red_bins*num_green_bins*num_blue_bins;

A = imcolourhist(Inp1, num_red_bins, num_green_bins, num_blue_bins);%input image histogram
srcFiles = dir(strcat(Dir,'\*.jpg'));  
B = zeros(num_bins, 100); % hisogram of other 100 images in category 1
ptr=1;
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat(Dir,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
    I = imread(filename);% filter image
    B(:,ptr) = imcolourhist(I, num_red_bins, num_green_bins, num_blue_bins); 
    ptr=ptr+1;                                                   
end

%normal histogram intersection
a = size(A,2); b = size(B,2); 
K = zeros(a, b);
for i = 1:a
  Va = repmat(A(:,i),1,b);
  K(i,:) = 0.5*sum(Va + B - abs(Va - B));
end


%PR curve creation
sims=K;
  for i=1: 100 % number of relevant images for dir 1
     relevant_IDs(i) = i;
  end

 num_relevant_images = numel(relevant_IDs);

 [sorted_sims, locs] = sort(sims, 'descend');
 locations_final = arrayfun(@(x) find(locs == x, 1), relevant_IDs);
 locations_sorted = sort(locations_final);
 precision = (1:num_relevant_images) ./ locations_sorted;
 recall = (1:num_relevant_images) / num_relevant_images;
 plot(recall, precision, 'b.-');
 xlabel('Recall');
 ylabel('Precision');
 title('Precision-Recall Graph');
 axis([0 1 0 1.05]); 
 grid;
 toc;
end
```

Elapsed time is 12.700687 seconds.

Comment: My opinion when I have read the question: WOW 1000 images in 12 seconds in Matlab, pretty fast! :P Hope someone can help. BTW, to see what takes more time, you should "execute and time" your code, Matlab will tell you what takes more time

Comment: Without porting your code over to MEX, this is as fast as you can get it... especially doing retrieval on 1000 images in 12 seconds.  Most unoptimized image retrieval mechanisms that I have seen take much longer.  Consider yourself lucky here!